# Issues with Sonata Admin template?

Tags: php, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

I am installing Symfony 2.3.x and sonata admin bundle, but when it is installed, the admin panel is shown in a wrong way (see the screen capture).

This problem has appeared when I run composer update command. Before that, my sonata admin panel looks nice.

Any idea?  Could be a problem with any template of sonata? (Icons from sonata not appear).

Thank you!
[image: sonata admin current appearance :(]

Comment: Can you please try running `php app/console assets:install web`, `php app/console cache:clear` and then `php app/console assetic:dump`?

Comment: Yes, but that does not solve the problem :(

Comment: It is a problem with versions in composer file. Testing with another version, these template issues are disappearing...

Comment: Ah so it seems. I've found the issue on GitHub, making an answer for you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is a dependency between the `dev-master` versions of `SonataCoreBundle` and `SonataAdminBundle` that breaks if any older version is used between either. [Here is a GitHub issue regarding the problem](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2524)

The solution is to use the `~2.3` Composer version tag of `SonataAdminBundle` instead of `dev-master`, or run `composer require sonata-project/core-bundle dev-master` so that it exceeds the minimum requirement of `~2.2` for `SonataCoreBundle` in the `composer.json` file of `SonataAdminBundle`. Then run `composer update` to fix all of the dependencies.